# google place autocomplete on server side with google-maps-services-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use place autocomplete on server side with google-maps-services-js. And want to restrict to specific country. For example want to get results only in France. But i cant get the result that i wanted. What am i doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
const {Client} = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js");

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const client = new Client({});

  client
  .placeQueryAutocomplete({
    params: {
      locations: [{ lat: 35.6667, lng: 39.1667}],
      key: GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY,
       input: "par",
      language: "en",
      components:[{'country': "fr"}]
    },
    timeout: 1000 // milliseconds
  })
  .then(r => {
    res.json(r.data);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    res.json(e);
  });
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What was wrong? How did you fix it? @Emre

Comment: Sorry newly saw the question. Removed array at locations and object at components  here is the code   client
.placeAutocomplete({
  params: {
    location:{ lat: 38.9637, lng: 35.2433 },
    radius:100,
    types: "(cities)",
    key: key,
    input: "kemer",
    language: "tr",
    components: ["country:tr"]
 },
 timeout: 1000 // milliseconds
 })